# Where to see a list of Azure AD roles that a serivice princple have?

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-cli

[image]

As shown in the picture, I'm in "Azure AD" -> "Enterprise applications" blade -> then open up my service principle details.

All I want to know is what **Azure AD role** (not Azure role RBAC) does this SP currently has.

I checked the "Roles and administrators" blade, looks like all it does is show a list of what role can be assigned to this SP but not what has already been assigned.

To me, this blade is so misleading and useless. (I was thinking this SP has already assigned this many roles....)

I even tried the "az ad sp show" command, it does not show what Azure AD role is assigned to this SP neither.

Where can I see it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can see this from the Portal, but you can find out with the below.
`Get-AzureAdMsRoleAssignment` requires the AzureADPreview module

```
# the Enterprise Application's object ID
$appObjectId = ""

$roles = @()
$rolesAssignedId = (Get-AzureAdMsRoleAssignment -filter "PrincipalId eq '$appObjectId'").RoleDefinitionId
foreach ($roleId in $rolesAssignedId)
{
    $roleName = (Get-AzureADDirectoryRoleTemplate | where {$_.ObjectId -eq $roleId}).DisplayName
    $roles += $roleName
}
$roles
```

Comment: Thanks, tested and accepted as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a tiny dropdown button next to `Search` bar, that's where you can toggle between `Assignable: yes` and `Assignable: no`.

When you set to `no`, you see the roles your sp is assigned at AD level.
In our case, "Directory readers" & so on., which are AD level roles rather RBAC ones.

[image: AD roles of SP]

Comment: Haha I think you got misled by this horrible UI as well. All it does is show you a list of "available" roles that you can assign instead of what is assigned already. If you take another look at your screenshot. It just showed you almost all the roles including the "global admin", you probably never assigned it.

Comment: Oh, yeah! Thanks for correcting me. But me as a user can see the role on the portal but not sp. I'll see if I can find something with cli..

Comment: any luck? seems can't find any command

Answer (score 0):

This is not done at the SP level, you need to review role assignments at the scope they are assigned (Management Group, Subscription, etc).  If you think about it, it makes sense.  If you just saw the role **Owner**, that wouldn't mean much if you didn't see the scope it is assigned to. Owner of an RG is much different than an Owner of a Subscription.

You can download role assignments at a scope in CSV or JSON formats. Follow these steps to download role assignments at a scope.

In the Azure portal, click **All services** and then select the scope where you want to download the role assignments. For example, you can select Management groups, Subscriptions, Resource groups, or a resource.

- Click the specific resource.
- Click **Access control (IAM)**.
- Click **Download role assignments** to open the Download role assignments pane.

[image: Access control - Download role assignments]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-list-portal

Comment: Thanks for answering, but "owner" is RBAC role which I don't care. I was asking for Azure AD roles. They are totally different.  @scottwtang seems got the right script.